# Using mongoexport/mongoimport to export in csv format for embeded documents

Tags: mongodb, csv

How to properly export embeded documents in csv formats.

I would normally use this command for non-embeded documents:

**mongoexport --db db_name -c collection_name --csv -f "field1,field2"**

But how would you do for embeded documents. Suppose collection_name document has embeded_doc embeded in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use the same syntax:

If you have a document with field **name** that is a document, such as name: { first: "kay" }, you can still do:

```
mongoexport --db db_name -c collection_name --csv -f "name"
```

If you just want to export the field **first** in the embedded document **name**

```
mongoexport --db db_name -c collection_name --csv -f "name.first"
```